# How to install Ubuntu Software Center on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

Each time I try installing **software-center ** on Kali, I get:

> E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

Comment: That's strange because it's [in the repository](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/s/software-center/)... you could try just downloading the file manually.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the repositories first.

1. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add these two lines

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
   deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
   ```
2. In terminal type `apt-get update`
3. then try `apt-get install software-center`

It should work.

Comment: It does not work now. I know it's an old answer...

Answer (score 0):

for kali-linux and i think other Linux distributions you can install instead  **synaptic** package manager  or **gnome-software** which is like Ubuntu software manager

install synaptic with just simply

> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install synaptic
> ```

and you can install gnome-software with the following steps

> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install gnome-software
> ```

after that add these repositories  /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://kali.download/kali/ kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

and run it with `gnome-software`
if you didn't find the package in gnome-software search for it in synaptic

check this blog
https://linuxconfig.org/gui-software-installers-for-kali-linux

Answer (score -1):

This should be in your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://kali.download/kali/ kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Then:

```
apt-get update
```

And:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) says "If you want to install additional tools and software (such as signal) outside of what Kali has to offer, you may need to include an extra repository for this to happen. Please do not alter /etc/apt/sources.list, as this is used for the Kali Linux Operating System. Any extra tools and software needs to be placed into their own file in the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/" ...

Comment: ... and "Likewise, adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break."

Comment: Nothing broke since 6 months I'm using it. Also if Kali had software center working as it should (because it is included in the original installation at the first place, IT JUST DOES NOT WORK), users wouldn't have to research to make it work. 
Also nobody tried "to put Ubuntu on Kali".